# Allow up/downvotes on close/open proposals

Tags: discussion, security

It seems as if any five people can go around and start mass-closing questions with enough reputation.

What security do we have against this?

Comment: any 5 people can go around mass-opening closed questions. and we have the flag system/contact page/this meta to report abuse. (both close and reopen options are restricted behind reputation too)

Comment: Not much, given my [track-record](http://stackoverflow.com/review/close/stats). But if you have a question that you feel is incorrectly closed any 5 other (or the same) trusted users can also re-open if they see fit.

Comment: Did you notice your title and question body don't seem to belong to each other?

Comment: so.... that's pretty much how Stack was always meant to work. The security for the community that can cause this is... the community that can revert this!

Comment: @rene The title is a solution to the problem described in the answer.  Granted, it's not well explained.

Comment: @Servy you're not known for your humor but that is a great comment...

Comment: SO has always relied on the good-will of the people that contribute and moderate the site.  Any kind of collusion between participants that aim to destroy the usefulness of the site is detected *very* quickly and swiftly dealt with by the moderators.

Comment: @rene considering the tags a the handle, everything makes sense

Answer (score 11):

> What security do we have against this?

5 users, or one moderator, going around reopening the questions, if they don't merit closure.  Additionally, if there's evidence that the users were closing questions they knew that they shouldn't have, rather than simply having an honest disagreement of opinion over whether closure is appropriate, then a moderator could take further actions to stop the user(s) from continuing to cast close votes.